# Javascript image uploader/picker in a flask web app?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm trying to make a basic CMS with flask and I'm now thinking about images. I am going to use a javascript editor for the content area (like TinyMCE or CKedit), but I want to be able to upload images and have an image picker to insert them into the text editor field.

I can find little scrips for this around the net, but I can find anything with a python back end. Does anybody know of anything I could use? If it's just a javascript picker and upload form, that's ok—I can make the python back end.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can upload image and place into textarea with TinyMCE

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/) in the flask documentation recommends some rich UI solutions at the bottom as well as how to properly handle file uploads. There's also the extension [Flask-Uploads](http://Flask-Uploads) which allows you to upload your assets in "sets".